# How to fetch users instead of top tweets from twitter via tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using tweepy with python (flask) for a small project. I want to fetch users against a query from twitter. Currently I am using cursor object and it returns me tweets. But I want to fetch users instead of tweets.

I think what I am getting right now via cursor is the top results so I want the results in People tab instead of Top tab.

Any idea how should I do that?

Screenshot is attached for what I want!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zGUm.png

Comment: show us some useful code

Comment: @cizario thank you for your interest. Problem has been solved. I have posted the solution below!

Comment: perfect and just accept it (green tick) so others may know.

Comment: It says, I have to wait 2 days to green tick it. I will do, once allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in tweepy documentation.
After basic twitter auth:

```
twitterAuth = twitterClient()
api = twitterAuth.get_twitter_client_api()
api.search_users(q, 20, 1)
```

Here q is your search term, 20 is the number of results per page (max 20 allowed) and 1 indicates the page number from where you want to collect the users. For example if you want to fetch users from 1st page it will be 1 else any other page number.

Hope this helps everyone!